# How to combine the distinct values from the results of multiple aggregate concatenations?

Tags: sql

Sketch of the `select` query:

```
SELECT post.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.tag), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT also_tags.tag)
FROM post
...etc...
```

`tags` and `also_tags` are joined to a `post` via join tables, the "tag" tables only contain the actual tag data (nothing to do with the post): example row that might be in both "tag" tables -> `{id (number): 2, tag (string ): "iamatag"}` There might/are duplicate "tag" values.

I want **combine** the results of both `GROUP_CONCAT` expressions **but** I want to apply `DISTINCT` to the combined set. My experience, and understanding, is `GROUP_CONCAT(expr1 || expr2)` just does a string concatenation of both expressions so `DISTINCT` doesn't work.

Is this even possible in SQL? Or should I be doing the processing another way? Say I'm not the owner of the data.

Comment: Unfortunately you have not shown anything approaching your full query, so I cannot give a proper answer with a working example. However, it should be possible to achieve what you want via a sub-query or cte.  Something along the lines of ´SELECT tags.tag UNION SELECT also_tags.tag´ and then do your `GROUP_CONCAT` on a ´SELECT DISTINCT´ from this union.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (GROUP_CONCAT is a product specific function.)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UNION` will stitch rows together from multiple tables into one result AND it will also remove duplicates at the same time. So just union the tag tables before joining to the posts. Nb, now you don't need to include distinct into the group_concat.

```
SELECT post.id, GROUP_CONCAT(alltags.tag)
FROM post
join (
    select post_id, tag from tags
    union
    select post_id, tag from also_tags
   ) alltags on posts.post_id = alltags.post_id
Group by post.id
```

Comment: No GROUP BY needed?

Comment: Just perfect Paul Maxwell, I think I was too focused on some "aggregate" function solution that would allow the concatenation of multiple fields together (`GROUP_CONCAT` is just the one that was available for this proof of concept. It could've been any other.) Creating a sub query works well enough -- even if it has me considering how the relationships and data are being persisted.